# How to recall in originate command with dialplan?

Tags: asterisk, sip

I try to realize this scheme – Call to mobile number via SIP thought asterisk originate command with dialplan.

I run command:

```
asterisk -rx "channel originate SIP/79887772211@sip extension 400@dialplan"
```

And my dialplan:

```
[dialplan]
exten => 400,1,Answer()
exten => 400,3,Playback(hello-world)
exten => 400,4,Hangup
```

Now, When I run command I got call on number 79887772211 and when I answer I hear hello world audio.

Now I want to add recall if number 79887772211 is now answer.

I try:

```
[dialplan]
exten => 400,1,Answer()
exten => 400,3,RetryDial(hello-world|5|3|SIP/79887772211@sip|5|d)
exten => 400,3,Playback(hello-world)
exten => 400,4,Hangup
```

But it doesn’t work =( 
What I do wrong?

**UPDATE**

I change my dialplan to this:

```
[outbound]
exten=>_x.,1,verbose( calling to ${EXTEN})
same=>n,Set(CALLERID(num)=${calleridnumber}) ;callerid to use
same=>n,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@sip,25) ;trunk to use
same=>n,RetryDial(hello-world|5|3:SIP/${EXTEN}@sip|5|d)

exten=>_xxx,1,verbose( calling to ${EXTEN})
same=>n,Set(CALLERID(num)=${calleridnumber}) ;callerid to use
same=>n,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN},25)

[play]
exten=>s,1,Noop(///${caller}///)
same=>n,Answer()
same=n,Playback(demo-thanks)
same=>n,MusicOnHold(default)
same=>n,Hangup()
```

And now I can run command:

```
asterisk -x "channel originate Local/79887772211@outbound extension s@play"
```

and call works, bit if I drop call, asterisk doesn’t recall me.

Why RetryDial not works?

Answer (score -1):

```
pro-sip*CLI> core show application Originate 

  -= Info about application 'Originate' =- 

[Synopsis]
Originate a call. 

[Description]
This application originates an outbound call and connects it to a specified
extension or application.  This application will block until the outgoing call
fails or gets answered.  At that point, this application will exit with the
status variable set and dialplan processing will continue.
This application sets the following channel variable before exiting:
${ORIGINATE_STATUS}: This indicates the result of the call origination.
    FAILED
    SUCCESS
    BUSY
    CONGESTION
    HANGUP
    RINGING
    UNKNOWN: In practice, you should never see this value.  Please report it to
    the issue tracker if you ever see it.

[Syntax]
Originate(tech_data,type,arg1[,arg2[,arg3[,timeout]]])

[Arguments]
tech_data
    Channel technology and data for creating the outbound channel.             
             For example, SIP/1234.
type
    This should be 'app' or 'exten', depending on whether the outbound channel
    should be connected to an application or extension.
arg1
    If the type is 'app', then this is the application name.  If the type is
    'exten', then this is the context that the channel will be sent to.
arg2
    If the type is 'app', then this is the data passed as arguments to the
    application.  If the type is 'exten', then this is the extension that the
    channel will be sent to.
arg3
    If the type is 'exten', then this is the priority that the channel is sent
    to.  If the type is 'app', then this parameter is ignored.
timeout
    Timeout in seconds. Default is 30 seconds.
```

Comment: How I can check ${ORIGINATE_STATUS} in dialplan?

Comment: That is just variable. Same as other variables. See asterisk variables

Answer (score -1):

**SOLUTION:**

I edit dialplan and now its works =)

```
[play]
exten=>s,1,Noop(///${caller}///)
same=>n,Answer()
same=n,Playback(demo-thanks)
same=>n,MusicOnHold(default)
same=>n,Hangup()

[outbound3]
exten => _x.,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@sip,15,t)
exten => _x.,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}"!="ANSWER"]?redial1)
exten => _x.,n(redial1),Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@sip,15,t)
   same => n,Set(secondary=79001112233)
   same => n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}"!="ANSWER"]?redial2)
   same => n(redial2),Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@sip,15,t)
   same => n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}"!="ANSWER"]?redial3)
   same => n(redial3),Dial(SIP/${secondary}@sip,15,t)
   same => n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}"!="ANSWER"]?redial4)
   same => n(redial4),Dial(SIP/${secondary}@sip,15,t)
   same => n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}"!="ANSWER"]?redial5)
   same => n(redial5),Dial(SIP/${secondary}@sip,15,t)
```

I use command originate to run it, and everything fine:

```
channel originate Local/791114442233@outbound3 extension s@play
```

or run it via ARI:

```
curl -v -u admin:admin -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:8085/ari/channels?endpoint=Local/791114442233@outbound3&extension=s&context=play"
```